# Use a certain objects throughout the program based on a value at start

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing a program where at the start of the program I take the bit depth of an image. Once I have the bit depth, which is guaranteed to always be one of 8, 16 or 32 bits. Once I have the bit depth I do some processing on the image, and create a few new images based on the output. For creating the images I need to use specific classes, IE FloatProcessor ShortProcessor ByteProcess and their corresponding arrays, float[] short[] and byte[].

What I would like to do is instead of having a switch or a bunch of if's at every place I need to determine which one to use. The three classes are all extensions of a class, but even if I were to do it in a method, I would still have to return the base class and I still wouldn't know which type to cast it as where I am using it.

Edit: What I really want is something along the lines of if(depth == 8) #define type ByteProcessor etc for 16 and 32

Answer (score 1):

What about using Generics instead of inheritance?  My Java is rusty, so I'll use C++ to demonstrate:

```
template<class DataT>
class Foo
{
    public:

        DataT data

        void processData()
        {
            // Do something here
        };
};
```

If you still need a switch statement in the processData function, you would still avoid having to put it all over your code.  You may be able to use Generics in combination with the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically speaking, let's say that all three inherit from a base TypeProcessor class:

```
abstract class TypeProcessor {
    public abstract Image ProcessImage(Image input);
}
```

And, you have your specific classes:

```
class ByteProcessor extends TypeProcessor{
    public byte data[];
    public Image ProcessImage(Image input) {
        //do stuff
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Obviously, if your program holds a `TypeProcessor` reference, you can't access `data` directly (without doing a bunch of type checking and casting and stuff).

The proper solution is to move the code that needs to access `data` into the class itself:

```
class ByteProcessor extends TypeProcessor{
    public byte data[];
    public Image ProcessImage(Image input) {
        //do stuff

        data = whatever;

        FrobData

        Image ret = new Image(data);

        return ret;
    }

    void FrobData() {
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (data[i] + 1) % 64;
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously a contrived and very incorrect example, but it should give you the general idea.

This will introduce some code redundancy, but I assume that the calculations are different enough between different types not to warrant a more complicated solution.

Comment: The problem is I'm writing a plugin, so these classes are coming out of the main programs library. What would work perfectly for me right now is #define